# Generate ECDSA key pair in DER format

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I want to generate a *secp256r1* key pair in DER format using OpenSSL CLI.

I am using the following commands:

```
$ openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -outform der -genkey -out privkey.der
$ openssl ec -inform der -in privkey.der -pubout -outform der -out pubkey.der
```

However, the second command triggers an *unable to load Key* error:

```
read EC key
unable to load Key
139911012984576:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1112:
139911012984576:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:274:Type=EC_PRIVATEKEY
139911012984576:error:10092010:elliptic curve routines:d2i_ECPrivateKey:EC lib:crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c:925:
```

Comment: I use OpenSSL 1.1.0g. I will check if it happens with the master branch and if a related issue is open on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ecparam -genkey` by default outputs *both* the params and the key; in PEM the reader can separate these and select the key part, but not in DER. **Add `-noout`** to suppress the params. (Yes you want both `-out file -noout` even though it looks contradictory.)

(And I reproduced with 1.0.2l and 1.1.0f both built from upstream source.)